# Analytic spread of an ideal after reduction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,m)$ be a local ring and $I$ an ideal in $R.$ Let $l(I):=\dim \bigoplus_{n\geq 0}(I^n/mI^n)$ and $x\in R\setminus I.$

**My question is**

*what is the relation between $l(I)$ anf $l(I+(x)/(x))?$*

Comment: What kind of relations are you looking for? Of course, there is one which comes from the dimension of the fiber cones.